# How to configure CI to increase the percentage of test coverage before each Merge Request?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, jacoco

My company uses GitLab CI, unit / integration test coverage at the moment is about 60% for the project I'm working on.

We use the JaCoCo library to calculate test coverage. Is there a way to configure GitLab CI in such a way that it would be possible to merge new code only if the coverage was increased (by 0.2-0.5% for example)?